# Wi-Fi direct connecting issues

Tags: android, android-service, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I'm trying to pair a device directly to another device using Android's own Wi-Fi direct interface.

However I have issues accepting the incoming group invitation from a similar device.

From the client I've managed to get this error:

```
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511): Unhandled message { what=147487 when=-1ms     obj=network: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  isGO: false
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  GO: Device: 
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  deviceAddress: *CENSORED*
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  primary type: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  secondary type: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  wps: 0
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  grpcapab: 0
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  devcapab: 0
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  status: 4
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  wfdInfo: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  Client: Device: 
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  deviceAddress: *CENSORED*
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  primary type: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  secondary type: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  wps: 0
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  grpcapab: 0
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  devcapab: 0
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  status: 4
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  wfdInfo: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  interface: null
09-16 13:42:07.547: E/WifiP2pService(511):  networkId: -2 }
```

The GO (group owner) connects using the following code:

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
                    config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;
                    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;

                mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                        new FetchDeviceInfo().execute(device);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failure to connect: " + reason, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });
```

And the Asynctask executing is just to fetch the client IP address.

Comment: I've had a similar issue, even when connecting through the WiFi Direct settings page. It may be a bug in the WiFi Direct implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol for negotiating the group owner will fail if both devices want to be the group owner (config.groupOwnerIntent == 15). Anything under has a tiebreaker bit if the GO intent is the same and will succeed.

The way I connect two devices (using your code) is as follows:

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
    Random r = new Random();
    config.groupOwnerIntent = r.nextInt(14);

    mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    ...
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll give that a try later :)

Comment: I just found out that if they tie and they are under 15, the call can still fail. The devices are randomly assigned a tie breaker bit and if that bit and the GO intent are both the same, it will fail. Check out the negotiation diagram: [link](http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US20110225305A1/US20110225305A1-20110915-D00003.png)